# Python consuming API (Printful)

Tags: python, json, django, e-commerce

I am struggling to find a way to call on JSON generating from the following code.
How for example, Can I call a list of "name" available on the JSON?
Ps: don't worry about the Printful secret key; this is a test account.

```py
import json
import requests
import base64

key = 'xk7ov0my-t9vm-70z6:y491-2uyygexkkq6r'
key = base64.b64encode(bytes(key, 'utf-8'))
keyDecoded = key.decode('ascii')
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + keyDecoded}
r = requests.get('https://api.printful.com/sync/products', headers=header)

# packages_json = r.json()

test = r.json()

print(json.dumps(test, indent=4))

# print(test["name"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to print type of `test`, you will see that it is a dict:

```
print(type(test)) # dict
print(print(test.keys()) # dict_keys(['code', 'result', 'extra', 'paging'])
```

Than we need to extract `result`

```
print(type(test["result"])) # <class 'list'>
print(len(test["result"])) # 3
print(type(test["result"][0])) # <class 'dict'>
```

And in this we will extract `name` from the dict:

```
print([n for i in test["result"] for k, n in i.items() if k == "name"])
```

Output:

```
['Snapback Hat', 'Short-Sleeve Unisex T-Shirt', 'Short-Sleeve Unisex T-Shirt']
```